# Overflow в android

Tags: android, xml

Как можно разрешить дочернему элементу выходить за рамки родительского в android? Есть ли возможность сделать это так же как overflow в html или нужно искать другой вариант расположения объектов?[image: Сейчас это выглядит так][image: Нужно добиться такого вида]

Comment: Располагать виджеты со смещением позволяет FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону `FrameLayout`. Например есть такая разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="First is below"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=" Last is on top"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

которая делает так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот есть подобные обсуждения на enSO: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821684/is-it-possible-to-place-one-view-over-another-in-android), [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351354/android-constraintlayout-put-one-view-on-top-of-another-view/44378384)